# Strange behaviour of Vagrant Up command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrantfile

Whenever I run Vagrant up, I am getting the following error.

[image: Error]

Following is my vagrant file

```
default_box = "generic/opensuse42"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = default_box
    master.vm.box_version = "v3.4.4"
    master.vm.hostname = "master"
    master.vm.network 'private_network', ip: "192.168.0.200",  virtualbox__intnet: true
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, id: "ssh", disabled: true
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2000 # Master Node SSH
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6443, host: 6443 # API Access
    for p in 30000..30100 # expose NodePort IP's
      master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: p, host: p, protocol: "tcp"
      end
    master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = "3072"
      v.name = "master"
      end
    master.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      sudo zypper refresh
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install bzip2
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install etcd
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install apparmor-parser
      curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
    SHELL
  end
```

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message provides the info you require:

```
in 'parse': Illformed requirement ["v3.4.4"] (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
```

It basically advises that there is a problem with your version of vm requested from your Vagrantfile:

```
default_box = "generic/opensuse42"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = default_box
    master.vm.box_version = "v3.4.4"
    master.vm.hostname = "master"
```

The problem is that you have used 'v' to define the version, which cannot be parsed for the value attained for the 'config.vm.box_version' attribute variable - it should be :

```
master.vm.box_version = "3.4.4"
```

You can always double check your config for a vm from the Vagrant website, in your case [generic/opensuse42 - v3.4.4](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/opensuse42/versions/3.4.4), it shows that it should be:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/opensuse42"
  config.vm.box_version = "3.4.4"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that  `generic/opensuse42` has been expired so changing the box to `opensuse/Leap-15.2.x86_64`, solved my issue